# redirect subfolder/directory to other domain URL using IIS URL Rewrite

Tags: redirect, iis, rules, url-rewrite-module

I am looking at using IIS Rewrite Module 2.0 to redirect some URLs for content that is currently housed on our antiquated sister site.

We have 2 content types and 2 sites that couldn't be more different in terms of technologies employed. Our aim is to redirect urls from domain1 (IIS asp.net) to domain2 (NGINX static site) incrementally over the next year.

Redirect maps will be employed where necessary during this process. However, we have hundreds of thousands of urls and there will be instances where entire subdirectories of content will require redirection to domain2. Thus the need to create 'catch all' rules for certain folders will be required.

And to my question:

I'm looking for help with a rule that will allow for redirection of the following subdirectory:

http://www.domain1.com/Topics/People/social-services-work/

To the following URL

https://www.domain2.com/social-services/

As mentioned previously, in most instances a rewriteMap will probably suffice. However, there will likely be several areas of domain1 with hundreds of urls to be redirected to a single url on the new domain.

So looking for the cleanest rule that would cover an instance such as the one above.

Any help or steering in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Kind regards,

C